# Can't retrieve a property on search results. (Property doesn't exist or is used in a manner inconsistent with schema settings)

Tags: search, search-results, 2016, managed-property, crawled-property

I have SP2016 Farm with a site collection and I created a library and activated the rating feature to rate my documents. Then, I'm trying to sort the search results with AverageRating property, but I'm getting this error: *"(Property doesn't exist or is used in a manner inconsistent with schema settings)"*
The weird thing is that I can get the value with the SearchQueryTool so the property is indexing correctly.

I can sort with other properties and it's working ok.

Can anyone give me some help on this, please?
Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are unable to sort by that field because, by default, `AverageRating` is not sortable.

If you look at `Site Settings` -> `Search Schema` (in `Site Collection Administration` section) -> Search for `AverageRating` and look at its properties.  The `Sortable` value is set to `No`.

This is why you are able to see the value using the SearchQueryTool.  You can pull the value, you just can't sort on it.

I would recommend, assigning the crawled property `ows_AverageRating` to one the `RefinableDecimalXX` managed properties and sort on that.  Remember after you change the search schema you need to reindex the site.